# Modifying ros navigation map with image editor

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, stack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I recently used gmapping on a robot I built to scan a room using a kinect sensor and converting pointcloud to scan.

The room was scanned with some noise so I edited the map using photoshop (on a different computer) but when I tried navigating the map with the new modifications the robot couldn't be localizaed properly and amcl and move_base started giving errors of type "off map" and "unable to get robot pose".

I read somewhere that it should be OK to edit a map using gimp or photoshop and even change PGM to PNG but I did not find a lot of details on best practice.

I think that the format or resolution of the image is somehow being affected during the editing, especially since I am generating the map on Linux and then editing on macosx.

Do you have any tips on bets practice on editing an existing map to ensure issues with navigation?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257399/modifying-ros-navigation-map-with-image-editor/) by [dgrixti](https://answers.ros.org/users/28978/dgrixti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2017-03-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my experience, manually **editing** a gmapping generated **map** is **not a good idea**.  AMCL based localization suffers and you will get unforeseen issues.

Usually one wants the map to *look pretty*, but this is not usually the case. Sensor noise, reflections and other perturbations will make the map look *ugly*. Anyway a **machine generated map does not need to be aesthetically pleasant**, since the target audience of the map are robots. **Manually *beautifying* the map might remove vital information from it.**

If you want a *pretty* map for visualization purposes, I would recommend to **make a copy** of the original map, make any *beautification* in the copy and **publish it on a different topic**.

In **real scenarios** it is not rare to see a */map* topic with the **raw map for the robot** to use and a */map_for_gui* with the *beautified* **copy of the map for human visualization**.

I hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2017-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tjadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/31352/tjadhav/) on 2017-10-02**:
Thanks a million for this comment. this makes so much sense. I would try and beautify the maps and the robot had hard time localizing using AMCL. I stopped editing the map and the robot behaves properly.
Great tip about using a different topic for human visualization, cheers.
Tushar.